# make css sub menu full width of menu bar

Tags: html, css

using this css for a horizontal menu:

how can i make the sub menu items 100% with of the main menu bar (`<nav>`)

```
nav {
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; 
    padding: 5px 15px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}       

nav ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    color: #000000;
}

nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #666666;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```

here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9XLYE/ - hope it helps

thanks

Comment: Will you always have four menu items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too difficult I shouldn't think. You've already provided yourself a basic framework. All you would have to add would be:

```
nav {
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

And as long as none of the `ul ul`'s direct parents have a position set on them, their width will read from the `nav` element. Bear in mind that `nav` is naturally a block-level element, so if you implement that, your `ul ul`s will still be `width: 100%` essentially.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by making each submenu's position absolute in relation to a parent relative parent, the menu wrapping div.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/gespinha/9XLYE/4/

```
nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    position:relative;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #000000;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    color: #000000;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #666666;
}
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
}
```